# Cannot find the log printed by the ViewPager

Tags: android, debugging, reflection

I've set DEBUG to be true use reflection,and apply varies of filters (e.g: set package Name 'android.support.v4.view'; set log tag 'ViewPager'), but still i cannot find any log belongs to ViewPager.
IDE:Android Studio
Note:there is some log my code printed in logcat, like 'System.out', but there isn't any log belongs to ViewPager should've printed.

Comment: You should google - cannot see logs in logcat

Answer (score 0):

use android.util.Log; for log, pls check some sample apps have userdefined Log classes.